# State machine scenario: finding invariant

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, pattern-recognition, invariance

Alice, Bob, and Charles want to evenly distribute a dozen doughnuts. Initially, Alice has 5, Bob has 3, and Charles has 4. However, they want to do it according to the following rules:

1)  Bob may give a doughnut to Alice at any time.

2)  If Charles has an odd number of doughnuts, then Alice may give a doughnut to Bob.

3)  If Charles has an even number of doughnuts, then Charles may give or take a doughnut from either Alice or Bob.

4)  If Alice has at least 2 more doughnuts than Bob, then Charles may give or take a doughnut from either Alice or Bob.

i) Is the following an invariant: “(Charles has an odd number of doughnuts) OR (Alice has more doughnuts than Bob)”?

ii) Can the state (4,4,4) ever be reached?

Comment: I'm not even sure how to model the game, to test it out/visualize it in the start. Multiple rules can be applied in each situation (ie. 1) and 3) and 4) can be applied simultaneously...)

Comment: Start with your initial state of (5,3,4) and use the rules to generate all possible states. Do the same for each of those. You will either eventually get to (4,4,4) or see that you can't. Likewise, when you are through you can check if the condition in $i$ is indeed invariant.

Answer (score 2):

Define the following 6 states:

1. $A \leq B$ and C is odd
2. $A = B+1$ and C is odd
3. $A > B+1$ and C is odd
4. $A > B+1$ and C is even
5. $A = B+1$ and C is even
6. $A \leq B$ and C is even

Use each of the given rules to determine the possible transitions between these states.

For example, first rule: $(A,B,C) \rightarrow (A+1, B-1, C)$ or stay, giving the transitions:

$$1 \rightarrow 1, 1 \rightarrow 2, 2 \rightarrow 3, 6 \rightarrow 6, 6 \rightarrow 5, 5 \rightarrow 4$$

Second rule: C odd (so we are concerned only with states 1, 2, 3) and (A, B, C) -> (A-1, B+1, C)

$$3 \rightarrow 3, 3 \rightarrow 2, 2 \rightarrow 1$$

*Complete the transitions.* for third and fourth rules.

You'll find that there is **no transition to state $6$**. Its absence  means $(A > B) \lor C \text{ is odd}$ is always true, hence an invariant.

Now, can we reach $(4,4,4)$? Also do you see why we used six states in the answer, not four (say $A\leq B$ and $A > B$ for $C$ even and odd)?

Comment: @shoestringfries Did you face any difficulties completing the remaining steps? Feedback is appreciated. Thanks!